# Flex regex.replace whole string before parsing starts

Tags: c++, c, lex

I was wondering if it's possible to use a regex.replace in flex BEFORE the parsing starts.
Is there a predefined variable representing the whole input string?

Comment: Please tell what you want to do in detail in general terms, instead of asking a question that already seems to assumes one specific solution.

Comment: I wrote a grammar in bison which assumes every statement ends in a semicolon. I almost finished this project but when I reread my assignment I noticed a statement could also be ended with the 'end' keyword so no semicolon is needed. I was thinking the simplest solution was to use regex parsing to replace every 'end' in the input string with '\nend' which would result in the matching tokens 'SEMICOLON END' which would solve my problem. Since I guess this needs to be done before the parsing starts I posted this under de lex category. Is it possible for lex to return multiple tokens?

Comment: Where does the `\n` come from, you don't introduce it not comment on it. Why can't you have semicolon or `end` as two possible statement delimiters in your grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no variable representing the whole input string.

Think about it, this would not be possible for a generic scanner as Flex which must be able to handle very large file sizes, and can be used for a virtually infinite input in an interactive command parser.